# Getting entry ID from frm_email_message filter in formidable

Tags: filters, hooks

Using the filter `frm_email_message` in formidable I want to change the message body in an email but I need to get the entry id.

I can get it using a different filter `frm_email_value`. Is there a way to store a value from one filter to use in another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not quite the exact answer but I used a `$_SESSION` to store the value instead.